# Remote installation of Android apps

Tags: android

I want to allow user to install my app directly from my web-site, not through the Android market.
I'm working on a specific non-phone android device, which can't be connected to the Android market.
how can I accomplish such a thing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The device can download the APK files like a normal file. After that, the user can open it and gets prompted to install it by checking the apps permissions. This required the unknown source preference (*Preferences->Applications->Development usually*) to be checked.

If you want to create some sort of drive-by-download/install: Thats not possible for (obvious) security reasons.

Comment: The Web server also has to be set up to use the proper MIME type for the APK file (`application/vnd.android.package-archive`). Otherwise, Android won't know what to do with it.